# Is there a way to call a function of an already existing form in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, winforms

Is there a way I can call a function that is present in the parent form (users), where an instance of a second form(addNewUser) is called? What I want to do is when the second form closes, to execute a function in the parent form (users) which is updating a table so that the changes done in the second one (addNewUser) are updated in the table in the first form (users).

[a simple drawing of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuK8n.jpg)

Comment: You shouldn't have database access code directly in form code, extract it out into service classes and all these issues go away.

Comment: If you have object if form then you can call the instance method by the object otherwise you can call the status method by using the form class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an event driven paradigm like WinForms the best path is to use the events when there is one that you can intercept.
You can subscribe to an event from any class that creates instances of the event raiser. In this case you could simply bind an event handler to the FormClosed event raised by the second form.

```
// Suppose you have a button click that opens the second form.
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SecondForm f = new SecondForm();
    f.FormClosed += onSecondFormClosed;
    f.ShowDialog();
}

private void onSecondFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do whatever you need to do when the second form closes
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this for so long I can't even...

Comment: If you really want to dig in the event business then you can start to think about raising a custom event when you press that Add button and not close the second form so your user could add another entry without closing and reopening the second form. The custom event could even post custom data to the parent form (like an instance of a User class so the parent could add the info to its list)

Comment: I am using a database, so that you can add multiple users when the second form is opened. My onSecondFormClosed is just retrieving the new information from the database and outputs it in the dataGridView table that I have in my first form

Answer (score 0):

Define global variables to identify your instances of your forms:

```
internal static Form1 CurrentForm1 { get; set; }
internal static Form2 Frm2 { get; set; }
```

Then affect the variables as follows:

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CurrentForm1 = this;
    }
```

Somewhere in your code, you'll define the Form2:

```
Frm2 = new Form2();
```

Now, from the Frm2 code, you'll access to the form1 non static methods with:

```
Form1.CurrentForm1.UpdateMyThings();
```

And from the Frm1 code, you'll be able to watch the things on Frm2, like:

```
bool notified = false;
while (Frm2.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
{
    if (notified == false)
    {
        Message("Please wait...");
        notified = true;
    }
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

In this example, Frm1 checks if the backgroundworker #1 is still running in Frm2 (The Message function may display the message in a label or something).

Comment: A very good way of doing it, I just find it too complex (I know it's not) for what I am trying to do. Thank you for your response!

Comment: If I could share my thoughts I would also point the fact that having global _static_ variables in this way is very dangerous. You could end in a very buggy situation if you don't clear those variables when the form closes.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve, for the warning, could you be more precise please? I use those static variables with no bug at all, maybe I have a very specific use...

Comment: What if the Frm2 closes? The variable is still there pointing to a disposed form. If you try to use it again after the form (2) closes you will get a crash. Of course I know nothing of your current code and the exact context, so it is just a red flag warning in my head.